# How to take a long screenshot on Android with adb command?

Tags: adb

Does anybody know how to take a **long/scrolling** screenshot on Android device using ADB command?

Comment: Such a command does not exist on plain Android (may be there is a third party binary that allows to do so?). What you can do is make multiple screen shots and between each move the scrollable area using `input swipe`. Afterwards detect common parts and stitch all the images together.

Comment: Also think that unlike a browser that usually renders the entire content and then you can take the full screenshot even of the parts that are not visible, the android app probably has a couple of off-screen views and they will be rendered as you scroll.